# Remove trailing slash from URLs

Tags: url, htaccess

I would like to remove all urls with trailing slashes using the .htaccess file.
I have tried a couple peices of code suggested on other questions but does not work.

Any suggestions on how to do this by modifying the code below?

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png|pdf)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: For what reason do you want to remove trailing slashes, if i may ask? e.g. when visiting ``/blog/url_title`` , would expect a list to be at ``/blog/``. Same for ``/blog/url_title/comments``, to me it does somewhat suggest a directory or a resource.

Comment: I agree with you but I am getting duplicate content issues in my webmaster account as urls /blog & /blog/ are seen as two separate pages by Google.

Comment: have you added a cannonical tag to the head? That should stop from duplicate content penalties

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what I usually have in my .htaccess for this (goes right after RewriteBase /):

```
# Remove the trailing slash to paths without an extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [L,R=301]
```